# Pass data from python script to HTML

Tags: python, html

At this moment i have a python script running on a raspberry pi which generates data. I want to put this data on a webpage.

I have installed an apache webserver on the pi and just put the generated data in the index.html

```
f = open("/var/www/index.html" ,"a")
    f.write("<p>'%s'</p>" % (Y))
    f.close()
```

the downside is that i constantly need to refresh the browser to see if data changed.

Is there a better way to do this? i have looked ad AJAX and PHP but i don't find a way to pass the data directlu from the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), which I use all the time for webapps. You can also take a look at [Flask Frozen](https://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/), which would let you use Apache to serve your content, but you get all the features of Flask when creating your content.

More specifically, for your exact use case:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
data_loader = lambda: range(10) # this function should load your data from some external store
@app.route("/")
def main():
    body = "\n".join(["<p>%s</p>" % datum for datum in data_loader()])
    page = """<html><body>%s
              <script>setTimeout(function(){
                 window.location.reload(1);
            }, 5000);</script></body></html>""" % body
    return page


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small WSGI app with a light framework, but that may be overkill for your purposes. A quick-and-dirty method requiring a minimal change to your project is to use the CGI module and turn on CGI handling handling in Apache. Using your example:

```
import cgi
print "<p>'%s'</p>" % (Y)
```

You will need to [configure Apache to enable CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html).

Python under CGI is slower than WSGI as the entire runtime has to start, parse the script and handle the request; WSGI is a running process. Try the CGI method; if it's too slow, take some time to rewrite your app as a WSGI app.